# Wiki content editor override

Tags: content-editor-web-part, wiki-pages

I have an issue which is probably specific to this product that has effected the content editor on the wiki pages for the site collection. The product 'wraps' the Telerik RadEditor within a solution which is deployed across the site collection, so the Telerik rad editor itself isn't exposed as a feature which can be enabled or disabled like it normally would, so I can't simply disable it at the subsite level;

At the moment both the Telerik RadEditor and the SharePoint RTE appear on wiki pages which causes neither editor to work properly. Ideally I just need to disable one of these editors somehow but unsure where to modify this from?

[image]

UPDATE 10/07

With the 'hiding' of the Telerik rad editor it will just take the whole content editable block away from the page. So the RadEditor takes over as the default editor for the content block; so its more than just hiding I need to do to get it off the page.
[image: hidden telerik]

What I have found is that i'm happy to use the RadEditor but there the link function is broken with it.
[image: SPEditorTools.js]

I've got a snippet of the markup if anyone can interpret it;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><title>

    Wikis - Home

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/7BF96C8B/search-7E1AFF02.css?ctag=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/7BF96C8B/wiki-ECF524AA.css?ctag=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/7BF96C8B/corev4-8A0ABD2F.css?ctag=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/7BF96C8B/Scholaris2010VC-87A677BA.css?ctag=0"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _fV4UI = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=BjQJs0OCQh3Zfydsdw2MYw%3D%3D"></' + 'script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery.js"></' + 'script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=sAjmR-pTg2NMyvDwB0cA05T1-JshXNT7Twnw8kE2vNKoHhzU-th5hTdmBUhKtqnO7R2Kdaak-fGFUOYr-jmwi3x1gr36y7MDVbYb_WNkWpXZUXhX1fWr9zemQUvywWKq26SAK-C7GJsL5MBCysQYjc31SM41&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4"></' + 'script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/blank.js?rev=QGOYAJlouiWgFRlhHVlMKA%3D%3D"></' + 'script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=q2t39_O6sl8fm-WYQHM789TYgY_X-q6X-rQMv_72Miu3gTQ_8y-MMqB6CwvV7sgsmcrFZ7fncF6BXLL-Z8z28iAXhzqJ5fXQ385CN3RzdwQt-SoKNH-SlYmHqtg5hjg4ZiZDu66ZOv20pD9pmQX5bPKILS7KGGnydLeSk32iewF0lwkP0&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4"></' + 'script>');
// ]]>
</script>
<link type="text/xml" rel="alternate" href="/myClasses/test11112/Wikis/_vti_bin/spsdisco.aspx" />
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
    </script>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Wiki Pages" href="/myClasses/test11112/Wikis/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=3617fb8b%2D6ac9%2D41ff%2D80a4%2Db0334d043ad6" />




<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /><style type="text/css">
    .ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Bottom_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
    .ctl00_wpz_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }

</style></head>
<body scroll="no" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" class="v4master">
  <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Home.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource" id="MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId" id="MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOTlPn_View" id="MSOTlPn_View" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOTlPn_ShowSettings" id="MSOTlPn_ShowSettings" value="False" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary" id="MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOGallery_FilterString" id="MSOGallery_FilterString" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOTlPn_Button" id="MSOTlPn_Button" value="none" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wikiPageMode" id="_wikiPageMode" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__REQUESTDIGEST" id="__REQUESTDIGEST" value="0x6617937A34509CD25F4D505F627323C9DD936CC6CF989F3E8208E11E241C5CF1DB9E212624AE0D3A0D91B55A4919FC270DF35F743CF9BE391D77B827491A2C98,10 Jul 2013 01:33:14 -0000" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext" id="MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow" id="MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="InputComments" id="InputComments" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wikiPageCommand" id="_wikiPageCommand" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="SPPageStateContext_PreviousAuthoringVersion" id="SPPageStateContext_PreviousAuthoringVersion" value="11" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName" id="MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName" value="Browse" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode" id="MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOWebPartPage_Shared" id="MSOWebPartPage_Shared" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOLayout_LayoutChanges" id="MSOLayout_LayoutChanges" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" id="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpSelected" id="_wpSelected" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wzSelected" id="_wzSelected" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName" id="MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName" value="Browse" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName" id="MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" name="MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing" id="MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" name="_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition" id="_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="SPPageStateContext_PreviousAuthoringItemUser" id="SPPageStateContext_PreviousAuthoringItemUser" value="1" />
```

Comment: I think, this markup is taken from the view mode, not the edit mode. When you are using dev tools in IE click on the refresh button inside this dev panel. And only then copy the html markup. The thing is I don't see RadEditor at all here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS classes and attributes of RadEditor and SharePoint HTML editor are different for the DIV that can be edited. I think, by removing SharePoint classes and attributes from this DIV you can keep RadEditor and vise versa. Try this jQuery plugin for removing SharePoint editor from a DIV:

```
(function ($) {  
 $.fn.SPNonEditable = function () {  
 return this.each(function () {  
   $(this).removeClass("ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").removeAttr("role aria-haspopup style contentEditable UseInlineStyle aria-multiline");  
  });  
 };  
})(jQuery);
```

Then, on a wiki page you can include this code:

```
    $("[contentEditable]").SPNonEditable();
```

As a result, the Ribbon's buttons are still there, but they become disabled. And SharePoint editor does not recognize the DIV as editable.

**Update:**

You can create a JS file  "wikiJS.js" with the code:

```
//if it's a wiki page:
if ($("#_wikiPageMode").length > 0) 
{
   $("[contentEditable]").removeClass("ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").removeAttr("role aria-haspopup style UseInlineStyle aria-multiline");  
}
```

Then put this file in "Style Library".

Then, on master page you need to include the ScriptLink control:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkWiki" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/wikiJS.js" Localizable="False"  OnDemand="False" />
```

I don't really like this solution very much  because it will disable SharePoint editor on all Wiki pages. That's why, you might want to modify the JavaScript to be more specific about the pages you want to temper with.

**Removing RadEditor**

Also, we could try to hide RadEditor instead of disabling SharePoint Editor:

```
var wikiMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value;
if (wikiMode == "Edit")
{
   if ($("#_wikiPageMode").length > 0) 
  {
   $(".RadEditor").hide(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after, I've been going through the templates and looking where to add the jQuery code to? Can you tell me where / what file I should be adding the function to?

Comment: yes, I've updated the answer.

Comment: very nearly solves it (will pay as the answer), I find that the script needs to be executed when I switched into 'edit mode'. If you know the classes for telerik that would be great since that's the one I'm seemingly having trouble with.

Comment: I wish I could see the resulting markup. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer. Let's see if it helps.

Comment: Ended up finding that I can at least get the Telerik Rad editor to work with the insert link option using this post; http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/sharepoint-2010/grid-editor-ajax-webparts/mosslinkmanager.aspx (namely changing this fix: All you need to do is to open the ToolsFile.xml / ListToolsFile.xml files and replace the

<tool name="SPLinkManager" text="Insert Link" />

with

<tool name="LinkManager" text="Insert Link" />

Comment: One last question is that I can't get the controls disabled unless I manually execute the script in IE developer tools, is this where the LoadAfterUI="true" can be used? http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html

Comment: oh. yes, sorry, I've forgot about it. You have to wrap all your JavaScript code in $(function() { YOUR_CODE }); construction. This will execute after UI is loaded. You can also set LoadAfterUI='true' but it won't be needed, I think.